# Java JDBC SQL rewriting one table to another

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, insert-update

Hello I have table "players" and I try to rewrite my results from "players" to empty  table "second_players". Now I have ony first result, but I want all results in my new table. How can I do it i Java JDBC ? A piece od code below

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/football?" +
                "user=rot&password=14&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
        System.out.println("connected");

        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM players");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            int clubId = rs.getInt("id");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO second_players(name, club_id) VALUES ('"+name+"',"+clubId+")");
        }

        closeStatement(stmt);

        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM second_players");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString("id" + "|"));
            System.out.print(rs.getString("name" + "|"));
            System.out.print(rs.getString("club_id"));

        }
```

Comment: Do it in pure SQL first, and then  select from that second table;

Comment: Use insert ... select ... syntax.

Comment: It's very likely you should have created a separate statement to execute insert query.